# How i can use scss with Underscore theme

Tags: css, wordpress, sass

I've been looking for many hours at how to use SCSS in the Underscore theme that I downloaded with `_sassify`.

When I open the folder and I see the `style.css` and the folder with scss files, the theme use css but I want change and use the `scss` file.
I don't understand how to use it.

What is the process to use scss? Can someone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor) to compile scss to css. The theme uses css, this will not change. You do your changes in scss - then scss compiles to css. A preprocessor can be part of your IDE, you can use programs like [Koala](http://koala-app.com/), [Scout](http://scout-app.io/), [Prepros](https://prepros.io/) or you use the sass command line.

You should start reading here:
http://sass-lang.com

Try compiling your first .scss files in a test directory with help of http://sass-lang.com/guide:

```
sass input.scss output.css
```

Then start tweaking _s.

Comment: Ok I have understand now, I was thinking that was integrate in the theme. In this way I have to use a esterna app and for convert the files. 
Probably the plug-ing the @Jonathan say do the some things. But i don't want use any plugin. Thank you i will do with Prepros.

Comment: https://github.com/Automattic/_s/blob/master/package.json
This was not always the case: https://github.com/Automattic/_s/issues/1149

Answer (score 3):

You need to follow the steps from this page https://github.com/Automattic/_s

**Setup**

To start using all the tools that come with _s you need to install the necessary Node.js and Composer dependencies :

```
$ composer install
$ npm install
```

Available CLI commands
_s comes packed with CLI commands tailored for WordPress theme development :

- composer lint:wpcs : checks all PHP files against PHP Coding Standards.
- composer lint:php : checks all PHP files for syntax errors.
- composer make-pot : generates a .pot file in the languages/ directory.
- npm run compile:css : compiles SASS files to css.
- npm run compile:rtl : generates an RTL stylesheet.
- npm run watch : watches all SASS files and recompiles them to css when they change.
- npm run lint:scss : checks all SASS files against CSS Coding Standards.
- npm run lint:js : checks all JavaScript files against JavaScript Coding Standards.
- npm run bundle : generates a .zip archive for distribution, excluding development and system files.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a few days how to change styles in Underscore Theme with scss files to css file. Earlier I worked with Gulp so I wanted to create gulpfile that will work. I created normal file with Gulp which at first didn't work - it worked in cmd, but on Wordpress nothing changed. But after adding a plugin WP-SCSS finally it works! So thanks a lot for your answer Jonathan and for helping me to find [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-scss/). Maybe it will help someone, so below I add the code from the gulpfile.

```
// gulpfile.js
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    sass = require("gulp-sass"),
    postcss = require("gulp-postcss"),
    autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer"),
    cssnano = require("cssnano"),
    sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");

function style() {
    return (
        gulp
            .src(paths.source.src)
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(sass())
            .on("error", sass.logError)
            .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer(), cssnano()]))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.source.dest))
    );
}

// $ gulp style
exports.style = style;

var paths = {
    source: {
        // By using styles/**/*.sass we're telling gulp to check all folders for any sass file
        src: "sass/**/*.scss",
        // Compiled files will end up in whichever folder it's found in (partials are not compiled)
        dest: "."
    }
};

function watch() {
    gulp.watch("sass/**/*.scss", style);
}
    
// $ gulp watch
exports.watch = watch
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the Underscore theme specifically, but I have used [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-scss/) in the past and I really like it. It lets you use SCSS with any theme and automatically compiles the files for you.

Comment: Thanks sure work but prefer not use plug-in. I will use Prepros to convert the files.

Comment: How do you configure paths in that plugin? How do you locate the path of a wordpress theme?